# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError during Solr index rebuilding

Tags: solr

We have upgraded our site from sitecore 8.0 u2 to 8.2 u4, everything works fine. I am trying to rebuild only 1 index at a time, after indexing some items we are getting error. We are using solr 4.10.3.

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=xyz_master_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">3</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Exception writing document id sitecore://master/{e3108f29-52d7-438b-939b-851a6df78a75}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=abc_master_index to the index; possible analysis error.</str><str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id sitecore://master/{e3108f29-52d7-438b-939b-851a6df78a75}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=abc_master_index to the index; possible analysis error.
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:168)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:926)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1080)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:692)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1976)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:698)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:712)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1507)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:164)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PackedLongValues$Builder.&lt;init&gt;(PackedLongValues.java:185)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DeltaPackedLongValues$Builder.&lt;init&gt;(DeltaPackedLongValues.java:59)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PackedLongValues.deltaPackedBuilder(PackedLongValues.java:55)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.PackedLongValues.deltaPackedBuilder(PackedLongValues.java:60)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.NumericDocValuesWriter.&lt;init&gt;(NumericDocValuesWriter.java:44)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.finish(DefaultIndexingChain.java:578)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:324)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:239)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:457)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1511)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:164)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:926)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1080)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:692)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1976)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst>
</response>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 batch)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is telling you that SOLR is running out of memory:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The heap size of SOLR defaults to **512 MB**, you can amend this by specifying a size in the command that launches SOLR, e.g.:

```
solr start -m 1024m
```

will start SOLR with a heap size of **1024 MB**.

[This guide](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#Java_Heap) contains information on how to approach deciding on a heap size. There are also pointers in [this question here on the StackExchange](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/622/how-much-memory-does-the-jvm-for-solr-need).

There's no one answer on how much memory you need to assign. The approach will be similar to the advice given on deciding on cache sizes for Sitecore - start with more than you need and then reduce this to a suitable level as you observe how much it uses.

Of course, if you have plenty of memory on your SOLR server, this may not be a worry. A good place to at least start will be to up the default and then try to rebuild your indexes to see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Kasaku, I was also thinking the same, it worked for me after increasing size.